# Norms for join tables

Tags: database-design

I would like to know what is the write design about join table to respect nf norms please ?
I have read the nf norms but I can't find clear specific rules about it.

For exemple, if I want to link a table containing "persons" and a table containing "cars", is the following design valid please?

| persons |
| --- |
| id |
| firstname |
| lastname |

| cars |
| --- |
| id |
| licence_plate |
| model |

| cars*persons |
| --- |
| car_id |
| person_id |
| amount |
| date_buy |

Comment: It depends on your use case - can a car have more than one `Person` associated with it? Are you collecting info about `Cars` without the associated owner info?

Comment: Thank you for your comment !
I fact I think I didn't ask my question clearly.
I already know that this representation is valid to the use case I want.
But I wanted to know if the representation was valid regarding all the NF norms please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your design is good if a person can have many cars and a car can belong to many people.

A couple notes on your naming conventions: the style I most often see and have adopted myself is to use PascalCase for table and column names, and full names for ID columns. I also plural tense for standard tables and singular tense with underscores for many-to-many join tables.

Example:

| People |
| --- |
| PersonId |
| FirstName |
| LastName |

| Cars |
| --- |
| CarId |
| LicencePlate |
| Model |

| Person_Car |
| --- |
| PersonId |
| CarId |
| Amount |
| PurchaseDate |

A couple of benefits when querying against these tables:

- It is clear which Id is which in your join. `c.CarId = cp.CarId` is more clear than `c.Id = cp.CarId` and less likely to be accidentally joined on the wrong column (which I've definitely done)
- You can tell visually that a join is a many-to-many by 2 entity names separated by an underscore.

Hope this helps,

Scott

Comment: Well put Scott.  Especially your first point about easily seeing the join ids.

Comment: Thank you very much for your so good answers !
I will change the naming conventions as you mention.
However, I wanted to be sure that this design is valid by every NF norms please ?

Comment: @shugyosha I'm not sure what you mean by "every NF norms". Can you provide a definition or page for me to read? To the best of my knowledge, the design conforms to 2nd, 3rd, and Boyce-Codd normal form.

Comment: @ScottMcCabe thank you for your answer ! Please find in thelink below the definitions of differents norms that I read before. I'm just not sure to fully understand them and so, I'm not sure that my design is fully compliant to them. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)